# Multiple melds for the same card

Tags: hand-and-foot

Can you put down 2 melds of the same card? For instance, a friend accidentally started 2 piles of 5's. Should they have been combined?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem #1 - No clear answer

There are a wide variety of variations on Hand and Foot. The versions I've played with people who "know the game" have always allowed a clean and a dirty of the same rank, and never allowed wild canastas. (The two variations I've learned both use the term Canasta for a completed meld; some versions of the written rules use the term books.)

**For clarity - some terms:**
**Clean Canasta**: No wild cards, 7 cards (or more)
**Dirty Canasta**: some wild cards, 7 cards (or more)
**Wild Canasta**: 7 Wild Cards.
**Extending** aka **Burying**: adding cards to a completed canasta
**Clean/Dirty/Wild Meld**: a group of cards that will become a canasta of the same type when built upon further
**Build**: to add cards to a meld in order to make it a canasta.
**Book**: synonym for canasta, also, to collect the completed canasta into a smaller pile, "closing" it.

- [Pagat.com](http://www.pagat.com/rummy/handfoot.html), however, says only one meld of a given rank per patnership, and allows wild canastas, and extending.
- [Gocampingamerica.com](http://www.gocampingamerica.com/blog/learn-how-to-play-the-card-game-hand-and-foot) makes no restriction either way on melds, and shows no scoring for wild canastas, and disallows extending a canasta, but allows larger than 7 cards melded before booking the canasta. *It also notes the lack of standardization in Hand and Foot Rules*
- [rummy-games.com](http://www.rummy-games.com/rules/hand-and-foot-canasta.html) does not allow multiple melds of the same rank, but allows wild canastas, and not extending.
- The versions I learned both allow a second meld (see below), extending, and disallow wild canastas. They differ on shuffling protocol, burying of wild cards and wilds per dirty meld. (One allows 3 wilds in a dirty meld, and burying wilds; the other requires a meld to always have more naturals than wilds.)

## In the Versions I learned

Yes, you can have a second meld of a given rank, provided:

1. the first one is dirty
2. you need a clean canasta in order to go out
3. you have your partner's explicit verbal permission to make the new meld.

Usually, this happens right after someone goes to their foot.

## In versions with no extending and no oversize canastas

You can close a canasta and immediately start a new meld of the same rank (provided you have the 4+ cards of specific ranks to do so).

## In your situation

Tactically, unless you needed the clean canasta, or the extant needs a single card to complete, they should have melded those 5's into the extant 5's.